# Why is parameter not propagated to post-build parameterized build?

Tags: jenkins, variables

I'm trying to apply the guidance I recently read at [how to trigger parameterized builds from a different build in Jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079228/passing-build-parameters-from-one-jenkins-project-to-another-jenkins-project) and https://plugins.jenkins.io/parameterized-trigger/ - **but this doesn't seem to work, and I'd like to ask the community for help understanding what I'm doing wrong**.

My jobs are set up thus:

- `foo2` is a non-parameterized build

  - `foo2`'s Build is `Execute shell` with commands:

  ```
  string1="123abc"
  export string2="456def"
  ```

  - `foo2`'s Post-build Action is `Trigger parameterized build on other projects`

    - It triggers `foo3`
    - It *attempts* to pass parameters to `foo3` with `Predefined parameters`:

    ```
    a_string=${string1}
    b_string=${string2}
    ```
- `foo3` is a parameterized build with two string paramters: `a_string` and `b_string`.

  - `foo3`'s Build step is `Execute shell` with commands:

  ```
  echo ${a_string}
  echo ${b_string}
  ```

**Question/Problem: when `foo3` is triggered, its console output are the string literals `${string1}` and `${string2}`, instead of the desired `123abc` and `456def` -- what am I doing wrong? How can I pass variables set during `foo2`'s Build stage to `foo3`?**

Output of `foo3` build:

```
Started by upstream project "foo2" build number 4
originally caused by:
 Started by user unknown or anonymous
Running as SYSTEM
Building remotely on builder-231 (docker-cleanup) in workspace /home/user/workspace/foo3
[foo3] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/jenkins2920927890739081404.sh
+ echo ${string1}
${string1}
+ echo ${string2}
${string2}
Finished: SUCCESS
```

---

Screenshots:

`foo2`'s Build and Post-build action to trigger `foo3`:
[image: foo2's Build and Post-build action to trigger foo3]

---

`foo3`'s parameters:
[image: foo3's parameters]

---

`foo3`'s Build
[image]

Comment: IIRC `string1` and `string2` will not available outside `Execute shell` step so the values of `a_string` and `b_string` will be empty for `foo3` build.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pipeline.

```
pipeline {
  agent any

  stages {

    stage('run job foo3') { 
      steps {
        script {
          
          string1 = "123abc"
          string2 = "456def"
          
          build job: 'foo3', 
            parameters: [
              // both is possible
              string(name: 'a_string', value: "${string1}"),
              string(name: 'b_string', value: string2)
            ]
            wait: true

         }
       }
     }
   }
 }
```